# MAMP's php interactive mode broken?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm using MAMP Version 2.0.5 (2.0.5) on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3. When I try to use php's interactive mode by

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php -a
```

it displays `Interactive mode enabled` and then hangs. No commands work.

This [forum post](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7878) says others have found it broken. Has anyone found a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine.

Type this after you see `Interactive mode enabled`:

```
<?php
echo "test\n";
?>
```

and press ctrl+d.

`test` will be printed.

Also see this question: [mac os php intratactive mode has no prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836915/mac-os-php-intratactive-mode-has-no-prompt)

To use the default `php` version that is shipped with OS X, you can do this in a terminal:

```
mv /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php.bak
ln -s /usr/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
```

Comment: @DavidXia That's the difference between `Interactive shell` and `Interactive mode`.

Comment: Is there a way to get interactive shell? I'll probably just uninstall MAMP and use the pre-shipped Apache and PHP.

Answer (score 4):

This is most probably caused by the PHP you are using not being compiled with readline support (--with-readline). Some distros dont compile with that option because of problems with the libraries or licencing issues, Debian for example - http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576218

Answer (score 0):

You have to install php5-readline extension

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline
```